# What's the meaning of defining "burst" with "nodelay" option?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

In the Nginx configuration, when you want to limit the request processing rate by using the `limit_req_zone` / `limit_req instructions`, I don't really understand the use of the `nodelay` option.
In my understanding, it terminates the requests above the defined rate without delaying them. So it seems equivalent to `burst=0`.
That is why I don't understand the following example :

```
limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
```

`burst` defines the number of requests which could be delayed, so what is the meaning to define `burst` if there is the `nodelay` option?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I find [`limit_req`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req) documentation clear enough.

`burst` is documented that way:

> Excessive requests are delayed until their number exceeds the maximum burst size [...]

`nodelay` is documented that way:

> If delaying of excessive requests while requests are being limited is not desired, the parameter nodelay should be used

Requests are limited to fit the defined rate. If requests are incoming at a higher rate, no more than the defined number of *requests per time unit* will be served. You then need to decide on what to do with those other requests.

- By default (no `burst`, no `nodelay`), requests are denied with an HTTP 503 error.
- With `burst`, you stack the defined number of requests in a waiting queue, **but you do not process them quicker than the defined *requests per time unit* rate**.
- With `burst` and `nodelay`, the queue won't be waiting and **request bursts will get processed immediately**.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, the documentation isn't clear enough for me.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the documentation by quoting it. Every word is carefully weighted in nginx documentation to make it concise: that is what is nice about it.

Comment: So what is the difference between `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=6r/s; limit_req zone=flood burst=0;` which allows 6 requests per second and `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=1r/s; limit_req zone=flood burst=5 nodelay;` which also allows 6 requests per second ?

Comment: So you had not understood my answer... The first case will process 6 r/s (hopefully process them immediately), while the second case will accept 6 connections, but process them 1 r/s (so at least 6 seconds processing time total). The only difference between 1 r/s with and without `burst=5` is that without the queue, only the 1st connection will be accepted while the 5 others will be '503ed'

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanations. It's a lot clearer to me now.

Comment: Just want to confirm about Bernard's anwser. If what Bernard said was correct, With burst and nodelay, the r/s rate of hit the webserver will be more than the defined requests from time to time, right?

Comment: @BernardRosset could you please clarify the "queue won't be waiting" — what do you mean by that?

Comment: This answer made me feel stupid. So I just tested out a rate limit of 1r/s. With a burst of 50, if I sent 100 requests concurrently, I get 50 requests rejected, and the other 50 complete one by one every second. With "nodelay" added, 50 still get rejected, by the other 50 complete concurrently instead of one by one.

Comment: So "nodelay" gives a trust burst, allowing requests to come in faster than the rate limit. A burst w/o "nodelay" isn't really a burst. It should have probably been named "queue length", not "burst". And "nodelay" should have probably been named "burst".

Comment: It all depends on how you interpret 'burst': On one hand, the docs are talking about burst of requests, referring to the non-linear fashion of requests in a Web environment, which might defeat you request limiting threshold (you define an average rate and then you use `burst` to accept deviations from a linear request rate while flattening it on the response end). On the other hand, you are referring to 'burst' as the immediate serving of requests, which is actually a special case handled for the occasion by the `nodelay` parameter

Answer (score 10):

With `burst` and `nodelay` specified I find it easier to understand the mechanism like this (the other way around than it is usually understood):

1. You allow a maximum of `burst` requests. With `$binary_remote_addr` that's the maximum number of requests that you accept from a given address. Every request increases an internal counter. When the counter reaches `burst` all additional requests are denied (and the counter is not increased beyond `burst` value).
2. This counter is continuously decreased at a rate specified using `rate`.

This logic suggests that it makes perfect sense to specify a high `burst` value (e.g. 100 and more) and a low `rate` value (even something like 2r/s). This handles normal browsing (a batch of parallel requests followed by a quiet period) better while protecting against sustained bot request stream.

Answer (score 9):

The comments on the original answer seem wrong.

The question at hand is what the difference between, say 
rate=6r/s burst=0
and
rate=1r/s burst=5 nodelay

The answers are great about explaining the difference when the nodelay option is NOT present -- in which case, the requests queue up with the burst, and are 503'd without the burst.

The original answer seems spot on -- with nodelay, the burst requests get processed immediately. And thererfore, the only implication of that is that there is NO difference between specifying a burst + nodelay vs. just specifying a the higher limit with busrt=0 in the first place.

Therefore, to more succinctly answer the OP question: the meaning of burst when nodelay is specified is the same as just specifying a larger rate without burst.

Comment: Thanks to have clarified this point, which was effectively the reason of my question.

Comment: This is wrong. Read my answer + comments again. If you still do not see it, let's make sketch: 6r/s on both configurations provided by Nicolas in a comment on my answer. 1st second -> both scenario will serve 6r, but conf #2 will store 5 in burst. 2nd second and onwards, still the same for conf #1 (all 6r served), but conf #2 will have removed 1 from the burst bucket according to a consumption fitting the rate limit, leaving space for 1r in the queue. The other 5r are thrown away.

Comment: @BernardRosset: but with `nodelay`, won't that mean those requests are processed immediately instead of queued?

Comment: @BernardRosset - please can you clarify about the above question - `but with nodelay, won't that mean those requests are processed immediately instead of queued?`

Answer (score 3):

I asked Nicolas's question to the guy who wrote the below post in nginx website.
[NGINX Rate limiting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx).His reply is as below

> In the former rate limit, nginx will accept consecutive requests at 1/6th seconds intervals. it will not accept a burst of requests that do not satisfy that minimum time interval. On the other hand in the latter definition, nginx will accept a burst of up to 6 requests regardless of the time interval between requests.
>   [Answer link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#comment-4677467778)

Comment: Hello @Gardener and welcome on Server Fault. Thanks for your well crafted contribution. The link to source is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the excellent Dan's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/844796) and on [the source code of nginx](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/5d5f0dcac4e3bbd4464aa1185d7fd51587a3119e/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#L402), a concise summary for the `nodelay` behavior seems to be the following:

- `burst` is how many *new* concurrent requests are allowed.
- `rate` is how many *new* concurrent requests become *old* per unit of time. (This updating happens gradually: once per request but not per second.)

Answer (score -2):

I'm suggesting to read this thread:
[limit_req_zone limit by location/proxy](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2013-November/041081.html)

and this answer:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196367/2596228)

Comment: Link-only answers are considered sub-par on Server Fault. Please provide useful content *here* and then link elsewhere for more detail if needed.