# Defining Burst and No Delay for NGINX

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I'm trying to limit my server (an API) to only allow 3 requests to be made per second (by IP, coming from Cloudflare), and after that the user receives an HTTP 429 code.

I don't want to allow anything in excess, that is, if the user makes a fourth request I don't want to hold it until the first 3 are completed, I just want to reject it immediately.

Reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/630157/whats-the-meaning-of-defining-burst-with-nodelay-option), [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620292/nginx-rate-limiting-doesnt-work-when-using-cloudflare-i-can-bring-down-my-site), I think I created a configuration that would solve the problem.
Is this type of configuration correct?

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $http_cf_connecting_ip zone=ip_limit:10m rate=3r/s;

    limit_req_status 429;
    limit_conn_status 429;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name seu_example.com;
        location / {
            limit_req zone=ip_limit burst=3 nodelay;
            # ...
        }
    }

    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `burst=3` would allow excess requests above the defined rate. So you would want to set it to `burst=0` to strictly adhere to defined rate.

Comment: Right, but if the 3 requests are made within the same ms interval.
Rate Limit will stop them, correct?